# Using string in managed c++ class, which is called from C# results in a procedure imported by 'mydll' could not be loaded

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I am building a C# application, which makes use of a class from an unmanaged c++ dll.
I have created a managed C++ wrapper dll around the unmanaged dll. When  I use std::string in the unmanaged class, I get an unhandled exception when running the program. The exception is "procedure imported by 'mydll' could not be loaded". below is example code. When I remove the std::string from the unmanaged header files everything works fine.
I am using VS2015, hope anyone can help me in what I am doing wrong.

regards

Sam

unmanaged c++ header file:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Student
{
private:
    char *_fullname;
    double _gpa;
    std::string _name2;
public:     
    Student(char *name, double gpa);
        ~Student();
        double getGpa() const;
        char *getName() const;          
};
```

unmanaged c++ file

```
#include "unman_class.h"
#include <cstring>

Student::Student(char* name, double gpa)
{
    _fullname = new char[strlen(name + 1)];
    strcpy(_fullname, name);
    std::string klaas = "test";
    //_name2 = name;
    _gpa = gpa;
}

Student::~Student()
{
    delete[] _fullname;
}

double Student::getGpa() const
{
    return _gpa;
}

char* Student::getName() const
{
    return _fullname;
}
```

managed c++ header file

```
using namespace System;
#include "..\\unmanaged_dll\unmanaged_dll\unman_class.h"

namespace man_dll {

    public ref class man_class
    {
    private:
        Student *_stu;
    public:
        man_class(String ^fullname, double gpa)
        {
            _stu = new Student((char *)
                System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(
                    fullname).ToPointer(),
                gpa);
        }
        ~man_class()
        {
            delete _stu;
            _stu = 0;
        }

        property String ^Name
        {
            String ^get()
            {
                return gcnew String(_stu->getName());
            }
        }
        property double Gpa
        {
            double get()
            {
                return _stu->getGpa();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using man_dll;
namespace test_program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new man_class("test",10);
            Console.WriteLine(test.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(test.Gpa);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Running the C# project with an outdated copy of the unmanaged DLL is an easy mistake to make.  Do avoid having to copy files by hand, ensure that all 3 executable files get built into the same directory.  Which should only require changing the C# project's build directory from bin\Debug to ..\Debug.  Or ensure that the post-build event is flawless and always copies the up-to-date version.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, that was the problem.